# When to read view's properties ( eg. widths) in activity?

Tags: android, view, properties, tableview, creation

I populate `TableLayout` in `OnCreate(..)` method.
I'd like to get width of each column of the table.
The problem is during `OnCreate(...)` method view has width set to 0.
Where is correct place to collect table widths?

I also tried `OnStart(...)` (from doc "Called when the activity is becoming visible to the user.") but the result was the same.

simpler example shows the problem (differ from upper description):

```
package xliiv.hello;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class __helloworldActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        int width = tv.getWidth();
        //this width will be 0! I expect that textview widths is not 0
        Log.i("tag", "" + width);
    }
```

Comment: paste your code, it'll give better understanding of your question

Comment: @RiNxX-Sarim one thing.. suppose i have ViewFlipper with 3 screens(?) and one button on each of 3 screens.. now i'd like to get button's width on fling.. which ViewFlipper's method should i override?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this in `onWindowFocusChanged()` , That will give the exact width

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    int width = findViewById(R.id.button1).getWidth();

    Log.i("tag", "" + width);

}
```